# One to Many hibernate Relationship saving primary keys differently.help me

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I have two entitys Reservation('One side') and GuestDeatails('Many side') DTOs. i have OneToMany Relation within these two entities.
When I am Saving Reservation('One side') primary keys are generationg like 1 in Reservation table,2 in GuestDetails Table. How to resolv this?...
My Entitys are :

Reservation Class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "reservation_id")
private Integer reservation_id;  

@OneToMany(mappedBy ="reservation",fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<GuestDetails> guestDetails;
```

GuestDetails Class:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "guest_details_id")
private Integer guestDetailsId;  

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="reservation_id",insertable=true,updatable=true,nullable=false)
private Reservation reservation;
```

My Controller is calling by POST Request.Some List of Reservation Objects containing GuestDetails objects will come :

MyController Class :

```
@RequestMapping(value="/saveResList", method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes="application/json")
public void saveList(@RequestBody ArrayList<Reservation> reservationList) {
    iReservationService.saveReservationList(reservationList);
}
```

My DAO Class :

```
@Override
public void saveReservationList(List<Reservation> reservationList) {

    for(Reservation reservation : reservationList) {
        GuestDetails details = reservation.getGuestDetails().get(0);
        details.setReservation(reservation);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(reservation);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

The OutPut for Single Record like :

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')  


Hibernate: insert into RESERVATION (agent_name, arrivaldate, arrivaltime,   billing_instruction_description, booker_name, booking_date, booking_type, business_source_description, cancel_date, confirm_date, contact_email, contact_person, contact_phone, corporate_name, departdate, departtime, double_room, group_name, guest_country, guest_firstname, guest_id, guest_lastname, guest_middlename, members, num_adult, num_child, num_rooms, package_name, plan_description, property_name, rate_code_id, remarks, room_no, room_type_description, sales_executive_name, salutation_description, segment_description, single_room, special_instructions, staynights, triple_room, updated_by, updated_date, updated_ip, reservation_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into GUEST_DETAILS (arrivedFrom, designation, dob, drivingLicenceNo, gender, guestAddress, guestCity, guestCountry, guestEmail, guestMobile, guestPincode, guestState, guestTelePhone, guestType, nationality, panNo, passportNo, proceedingTo, reservation_id, salutation_id, title, updatedBy, updatedDate, updatedIp, valid, visitType, guest_details_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

My problem is the primary keys are saving like :
In ReservationTable : 1,3,5,7......
In GuestDetails : 2,4,6,8....
help me please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you use the same sequence to generate primary keys values. Try to do this such way:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "reservationSEQ", sequenceName = "reservation_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@Column(name = "reservation_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "reservationSEQ")
private Integer id;
```

and the same way:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "guestDetailsSEQ", sequenceName = "guest_details_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Id
@Column(name = "guest_details_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "cguestDetailsSEQ")
private Integer id;
```

And of course you have to create such sequences called `guest_details_id_seq` and `reservation_id_seq` on your database.

Comment: thease sequenses are extra columns in specific table or not?

Comment: No these are just sequences. For example in postgres if you create table with primary key it creates sequence for this column by default (you have to find the name of this sequence in db).

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on auto-generated IDs being sequential!

There's many reasons why there might be gaps -

- In your case, you're using one generator (sequence) for two tables
- There might be two threads generating the ID at the same time, what if the first one then calls rolback?
- For performance reasons, there might be some caches that get lost if the DB server crashes, generating a "hole" in the sequence

The DB auto-generated **IDs only guarantee uniqueness** - that there won't be two IDs generated the same. It does **not guarantee that the IDs will be sequential**, or that all numbers in the sequence will be used.

If you absolutely require the IDs to be sequential, that at the very least requires that you not generate another ID until the transaction that generated the previous one ends - a huge performance bottleneck.